# How to use italic google fonts?

Tags: html, css, fonts

So I'm trying to use an italic version of the Google font Roboto.

This is the bit of code Google gave me for the fonts I chose...

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700|Roboto:300,100italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

I can get it to apply Roboto Slab and Roboto but I'm not sure how to get it to use Roboto Italic.

I can do...

```
font-style: italic;
```

But you can do that with any font and get a faux italic. I want the real italic Google font.

Anyone know how to use Italic Google fonts correctly?

Comment: You're doing it correctly. IF you're loading `font-weight: 100; font-style: italic;` it should display properly

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The correct way to apply italic font styles with google fonts is to use

```
font-style: italic;
```

for a bold font weight use

```
font-weight: bold;
```

The problem you're running into is that you're not including the appropriate font-weight for the italic font.

If you want `font-weight: normal; font-style: italic` to work, you need to include the `400`, and `400italic` versions:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic
```

The reason `font-style: italic` will work is because the font-declarations are set up to specify their appropriate style and weight. If you look at a the source for the link above, you'll find:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: ...sources...
}
```

Having the font-weight and font-style declared allows the font to take over at the specified weight and style. This can be used to *reverse* font-styles in situations such as where you might want a blockquote to appear italicized and emphasized text to appear normal.

If no overriding font-file is specified for the style and weight, then the browser will do its best to render a faux italic or faux bold.